# Are both a straight and a full-house possible on the same flop?

Tags: probability

I have been playing poker on pokerstar.net, and for several occasions, there have been a straight flush and a full house on the same flop/game, I just think that this is an impossibility. Just what clarification if this is actually a possibility.

Comment: Can you share the details of the hand(s) you're talking about here? Maybe that would help clarify any confusion.

Comment: I think the OP has basic misunderstandings of poker. I think you need to add more clarity to your question in order to better help you. BE SURE you know the definitions of (1) straight (2) straight flush (3) full house (boat) and (4) flop. As your question stands now, you have to remember that a full house only exists when a pair is on the board. And a pair on the board would make a straight and straight flush impossible.

Comment: There are two possible interpretations of this question: one has been addressed in the answers below. The interpretation I got was, "I saw two or more extremely unlikely bad beats on Poker Stars. Is PS cheating?"

If this is your question, highly unlikely != impossible. If you play poker long enough, you'll see every crazy combination, no matter how improbable, eventually.

Comment: I think the question is badly worded and asking for proof of a very basic and elementary concept.

Comment: Questions that can be very easily answered by doing a quick Internet search are not ideal for this site. This is why your question got closed.

Answer (score 5):

On the flop in hold-em, it is not possible for one player to have a straight flush (or even just a straight or just a flush) and another to have a full house.  A full house requires at least two cards on the board to have the same rank. A straight (or flush, or straight flush) on the flop requires that no cards on the flop be of the same rank.  These are mutually exclusive, so it's not possible.

On a full five-card board, though, it's entirely possible.  Say two players had these hole cards:

1. A♥ A⋄
2. J♠ T♠

and the board runs out like so: A♠ K♠ Q♠ Q♥ 5♥

Then the players' final hands are:

1. A♥ A⋄ A♠ Q♠ Q♥ -- a Full House, Aces full of Queens.
2. A♠ K♠ Q♠ J♠ T♠ -- a Royal Flush.

So, no it's not possible on the flop, but it's entirely possible by the turn and river.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible on the flop. basically for a full house, you need a paired board. And if there is a pair on the flop, there is no way to make a straight or a flush or a straight flush since you can't connect your 2 hole cards and the 3 cards on the flop to make a straight or a flush.